# Decimal data type for JavaScript (NodeJS environment)

Tags: library, javascript, node.js

I want a class for representing and manipulating a 128-bit decimal data type, a quadruple-precision floating point. I found [double.js](https://github.com/munrocket/double.js/blob/master/src/double.ts), but it supports only 106 accurate bits (double-double). I'm looking for something like [.NET's `Decimal` data type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-6.0) or something following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format).

I also need the class to have a method that returns its composing bytes, like `toBytes()`, which returns an array of bytes (16 bytes). Also tell me in which endianness they're returned.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Syncfusion Numeric TextBox component
https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-numeric-textbox

Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/bootstrap5/numerictextbox/default.htm

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Interesting, but my purpose was to build a compiler, not user interface.